# Spring return unauthorized when it is not data of user

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I have a endpoint, where the user sees the info of hic user account. But an user should only be able to see his own data and not of another user account. So my function looks like this

```
   @GetMapping("{userId}")
    @Operation(security = @SecurityRequirement(name = OpenApiConfig.USER_AUTH))
    public GetUserResponse getUser(@PathVariable UUID userId, Principal principal) {
        AppUser user = getUserService.findByUsername(principal.getName()).get();
        if(!user.getId().equals(userId)){
            //return ResponseEntity unauthorized
        }
        return GetUserResponse.of(getUserService.getUser(userId).orElseThrow());
    }
```

But as you can see I return a GetUserResponse, how can I return something like a ResponseEntity with unauthorized return code?

My GetUserResponse class looke like this

```
public class GetUserResponse {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    public static GetUserResponse of(AppUser user) {
        return new GetUserResponse(user.getId(), user.getUsername());
    }

    public GetUserResponse(UUID id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As it is written now I would simply remove the parameter and use the id from the principle thus making it impossible to request information about somebody else.**

If you would like to be able to let some users (admin, super etc) be able to use the same method then you could create your own exception and use the ResponseStatus annotation on that. Then simply throw that exception if the user id don't match up and the user isn't authorized to read other users.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, reason = "Invalid target id")
public class InvalidTarget extends RuntimeException {}
```

Then just throw that exception if the user isn't allowed to lookup others.

You can find more information about exceptions and spring in this blog entry:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an exception and return a generic response using ResponseEntity, you can use @ControllerAdvice annotation.

@ControllerAdvice annotation allows you to handle the exceptions in the whole application. It is an annotation-driven interceptor. Refer to [this link](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) to know more about exception handling and @ControllerAdvice annotation.

Refer to the below code to get more understanding about @ControllerAdvice.

Controller where the exception is thrown

```
@GetMapping("{userId}")
@Operation(security = @SecurityRequirement(name = OpenApiConfig.USER_AUTH))
public GetUserResponse getUser(@PathVariable UUID userId, Principal principal) {
    AppUser user = getUserService.findByUsername(principal.getName()).get();
    if(!user.getId().equals(userId)){
        throw new UnauthorisedException("Unauthorised User");
    }
    return GetUserResponse.of(getUserService.getUser(userId).orElseThrow());
}
```

UnauthorisedException.java

```
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    public class UnauthorisedException extends RuntimeException {
         public UnauthorisedException(String message) {
               super(message);
         }
    }
```

Class with @ControllerAdvice annotation

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdviceExceptionHandler {
   @ExceptionHandler(UnauthorizedException.class)
   protected ResponseEntity<?> unauthorisedException(final UnauthorizedException exception) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
 }
```